# InvalidCastException while casting to defined Type C#

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, types, casting

I have a Dictionary containing strings as keys, and objects as values in an abstract class.
I have two classes deriving from this abstract class.

One of the deriving classes works perfectly, all configurations and items are loaded and retrievable without issues.
However, the other class is giving me headaches.

When I try to get an object of type "Domain"; I get an invalid cast exception, although I am adding the value to the dictionary as said type.

Here is the code:

```
public sealed class UserDomainConfig: ConfigParser {

    public UserDomainConfig(string configFilePath) : base(configFilePath) { }

    public Domain GetConfig(string key) => GetConfig<Domain>(key);

    public override bool LoadConfigs() {
        return base.LoadConfigs();
    }

    public UserDomainConfig SetConfig(string key, Domain value) {
        base.SetConfig(key, value);
        return this;
    }

}



public abstract class ConfigParser: IConfig {

    /* Snip */

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the config.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The config.</returns>
    /// <param name="key">Key.</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The 1st type parameter.</typeparam>
    public virtual T GetConfig<T>(string key) {
        object output = null;
        try {
            if (!configs.TryGetValue(key, out output))
                return default(T);
            //return (T)output;
            //return output as T;
            // This is where the exception is occurring.
            //  I've tried multiple solutions to try to remedy this issue.
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(output, typeof(T));
        } catch (InvalidCastException ex) {
            logger.Error($"Failed to cast config { key }!");
        }
        return default(T);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the config.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The config.</returns>
    /// <param name="key">Key.</param>
    /// <param name="value">Value.</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The 1st type parameter.</typeparam>
    public virtual IConfig SetConfig<T>(string key, T value) {
        if (KeyExists(key))
            configs.Remove(key);
        configs.Add(key, value);
        return this;
    }
```

Any ideas on how to fix this, and/or why this isn't working in the first place, although it works like a charm with strings, bools, and ints?

Comment: So you are trying to cast to a `Domain` object? What is `configs` and what value is it giving you before you try the cast? I'm guessing it's a string or a simple value type.

Comment: configs is a Dictionary<string, object>, as mentioned in the OP.
As can be seen in the UserDomainConfig class, I'm adding a key/value pair, where the value is a Domain object. 
As such there are only Domain objects in the Dictionary, however I cannot cast from an object (which is what the values are saved as), back to a Domain object.

Comment: Have you tried to debug? What is the exact type of the `output` variable?

Comment: There must be something more to this as the code you post should work fine.

Comment: Just let the program output the type of the value. For some reason it's a string? How is an object (Domain) saved as a string in a Dictionary that takes string as a key, and object as a value?
As mentioned before, it works perfectly with the other deriving class, just not with this one..

I might end up adding the types directly to the class and let the inheriting classes decide what types the dictionary will contain.

Comment: What does `base.LoadConfigs` do?

Comment: @Beatsleigher it could be string only if you (or somewhere else in the code) explicitly invoked `ToString()` method before saving object into dictionary.

Comment: Try changing following From : return (T)Convert.ChangeType(output, typeof(T));  To : return output;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Convert` class only supports simple types, known by .NET, like `Int32`, `String`, `DateTime`. It does not support user defined or complex types like `Domain`. If you try to convert something to a not-supported type, the method `Convert.ChangeType` throws an `InvalidCastException`. The only exception is that it will work if the Original value (`output`) is already of that desired type; than no actual conversion is needed.

For more information, read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx

If you are certain the stored value is of the type `Domain`, than log more information. Something like this:

```
logger.Error($"Failed to cast config { key } of type { output.GetType() } to type { typeof(T) }!");
```

This way you can verify your claim that both types are the same.